# Automate a node.js build

Tags: node.js, batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

I am using `visual studio` to manage the code for my application, `visual studio online` as the `git` repository, and `node.js` to publish the UI.

Currently, when I want to publish an update to the UI, I have to open `node.js command prompt` and enter these commands:

- `d:` to change the drive
- `cd: d:\gits\application\application.ui` to change to the local application directory
- `grunt build:angular:beta` to publish the minified application

While the steps are simple, there has to be a faster way to do this. Is there a way to create a script to perform these steps automatically?

Please forgive me if this question has a seemingly obvious answer. This is the first project I have used `node.js` for publication and am not familiar with the tool. I don't even know enough to know what terms to use in a web search. Nothing I have found so far even gets me close to what I want.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a task in grunt that will watch for file changes and run commands for you.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

It would look roughly like this:

```
watch: {
  scripts: {
    files: ['**/*.js'], // or whatever files you want
    tasks: ['build:angular:beta']
  },
}
```

Then you would open a new cmd prompt and run `grunt watch`

Comment: after the initial run, will it run automatically whenever there is a file update in the application? Does that mean it is always running in the background? Or, would I run `grunt watch` any time I wanted to publish the update?

Comment: It will run in the background. It will trigger the task when you change a file that matches the glob pattern in the files array

Comment: or if your using npm you can do the same in your package.json file :)